# ios:convert html string to nsstring and display in uitableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

am doing my project using storyboards, in my project i will parse json data and display in simulator. here is my json

```
activityList =     (
                {
            activityTitle = test;
            activityType = Chat;
            apiKey = null;
            desc = "<p>asasasa</p>";
            id = 361;
            issueTitle = "Issue Created By m43 (194)";
            sessionId = null;
            status = true;
            token = null;
            when = "Sat, 30 Nov 2013 04:30 AM CET";
        },
                {
            activityTitle = "test match private";
            activityType = "One Way Video Streaming";
            apiKey = null;
            desc = "<p>test match private</p>";
            id = 335;
            issueTitle = "test match (190)";
            sessionId = null;
            status = true;
            token = null;
            when = "Fri, 29 Nov 2013 10:30 AM GMT";
        },
```

i parsed json and displayed all datas in tableview except this  `desc = "<p>test match private</p>";`
a, having problem converting that html string to nsstring. somwhoe how i tried and converted using this

```
 desc1 = [[items  valueForKey:@"desc"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"%@",desc1);
    NSString *itemTitle = [desc1 stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
    NSLog(@"%@",itemTitle);
```

it printed me this

```
<p>asasasa</p>,<p>test match private</p>,<p>test activity by m43</p>,<p>Test for chat activities</p>,<p>test 5 for admin</p>,<p>test ca activity title</p>,<p>test for video issue</p>,<p>activity for m43 by c31</p>,<p>test activity title community activism By u1</p>,<p>test 7</p>,<p>test</p>,<p>chat</p>,<p>rahul jaykar</p>,<p>test public unadkat</p>,<p>test activity</p>,<p>test chat</p>,<p>private activity</p>,<p>test session initation</p>,<p>join test&nbsp;<span>Your Activity Title</span><span class="required-indicator">*</span><span>&nbsp;</span></p>,<p>test 9</p>
```

and after converting to plain text like this

```
asasasa ,test match private ,test activity by m43 ,Test for chat activities ,test 5 for admin ,test ca activity title ,test for video issue ,activity for m43 by c31 ,test activity title community activism By u1 ,test 7 ,test ,chat ,rahul jaykar ,test public unadkat ,test activity ,test chat ,private activity ,test session initation ,join test Your Activity Title*  ,test 9
```

Now my problem is how to display this datas in label present in uitableviewcell;

here is my tablecell code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier =@"activismCell";
    CAviewCELLCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.activitytitle.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.idline.text = (NSString *)[array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.issuelabel.text = (NSString *)[array9 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.timelabel.text = (NSString *)[array10 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.typelabel.text = (NSString *)[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    sessid = (NSString *)[array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    token = (NSString *)[array6 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    apikey = (NSString *)[array7 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    for (int i=0; i<[array8 count]; i++) {

    }


    NSLog(@"%@,%@",sessid,token);
    NSString *stat =(NSString *)[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",stat);
    NSString *trimmedString = [stat stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if([trimmedString isEqualToString:@"Two Way Video Streaming"] || [trimmedString isEqualToString:@"One Way Video Streaming"]) {
        [cell.startvideo setHidden:FALSE];
        [cell.startvideo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca_video.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.startvideo addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    else
        [cell.startvideo setHidden:TRUE];
    return  cell;
}
```

have to display datas in orderly in cell.desclabel.text using indexpath for row.. pls help me how to do this

Comment: Could you clarify please, do you want to display EVERYTHING in once cell or ONE object per cell? By one I mean  activityTitle in cell 1, activityType in cell 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create array from plainText string by below way.

```
desc1 = [[items  valueForKey:@"desc"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"%@",desc1);
NSString *itemTitle = [desc1 stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
NSArray *arrNew = [itemTitle componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now change the cell label.

```
cell.desclabel.text = [arrNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: @Naresh: Note that this will produce wrong results if any description text contains a comma ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to create separate arrays `array1`, `array2`, ...
for each key. Instead of

```
array1 = [items valueForKey:@"activityTitle"];
// ... and later:
cell.activitytitle.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

you can simply do

```
cell.activitytitle.text = items[indexPath.row][@"activityTitle"];
```

And instead of separating and joining an array of "desc" elements, use

```
NSString *desc1 = items[indexPath.row][@"desc"];
NSString *desc = [desc1 stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.